# Excel Auto Send Emails via Outlook Randomly NOT Sending

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I've inherited development of an Excel userform which contains a send button to return the user's data back to a central mailbox. The tool has just been rolled out to a larger community and some users are experiencing emails not being sent. These are random events as the users can sometimes send the forms and it is not form specific.

The tool uses the following code to create the email:

```
Set ObjOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ObjOutMail = ObjOL.CreateItem(0)
```

and is sent via:

```
ObjOutMail.send
```

We had tested this with a number of users and never had any problems, but we now have a number of users who have successfully sent 1 or more forms but 1 or more have also failed, and they also can't resend the successful forms any more either.

There are no error messages, the Outlook "this could be a virus, etc." confirmation is fired as usual (we have not attempted to circumvent this) but there is nothing in the 'Sent Items'. The users are also able to send conventionally generated emails so there is no mailbox limitations going on.

The Userform is modal and upon sending copies the three user fields to "Sheet1", saves itself and mails itself.

Really at a loss to understand what's going on.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: To add we are still using Office 2003 on Win XP.

Comment: Just to add, I can 'watch' the ObjOutMail object right up to, and after the point where it is sent and it appears as it should with the correct recipiant, subject, attachments, etc. It's just not being sent.

Comment: Can you swap ObjOutMail.send for ObjOutMail.Display and see if it is attempting to generate an email at all?

Comment: It would help to see some code. Otherwise we're left guessing.

Comment: I'll try adding the .display, I have another form which works but uses the same code. When "yes" is pressed (outlook confirmation) on the other form the ObjOutMail object because void ("automation error" in all properties) and the mesage is sent. However with the troublesome userform this information does not change and the "sent" property remains = 'false'. all properties appear the same accross the two forms up until the form is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies, using the .display property showed me what was up.

The email is addressed to what I thought was an explicit address, however there is an extra '(MULTIUSER)' post fix which I didn;t realise was actually part of the address, DOH!.

Last week and similar mailbox made up of the same address but with a different postfix was added to the system. This ment Outlook couldn't resolve the address and didn't send the emails.

Thanks again.